# To have more present

Tags: present-tense

I am not a native speaker. I wrote:
"I want to have more present the things I love."

Someone who is native speaker and knows much more, corrected me:
"I want to have more availability to present the things I love"
But this has a different meaning, it's not what I wanted to write.

What I was meaning is that I want to have the things I love, closer, easy to find, easy to remember. Is there any problem with my original sentence. If so how can express that idea better?

Comment: Do you mean “I want to be closer to the things I love”?

Comment: The word "present" used here isn't wrong, but it's confusing because that word has multiple meanings, both as a noun and as a verb, and this particular meaning isn't even the more common meaning.  There's no way you could know this beforehand of course, but now you know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence as written is not grammatically correct. You are trying to say that you want a thing, i.e. a noun, "the things I love", to have an adjective applied to it, "present".

We do this in English with a "predicate adjective". The normal, simple form is:

> NOUN is ADJECTIVE

Like

> The things I love are present.

This is the word order. You can't say

> WRONG: The things present I love are.

Except maybe in poetry or song lyrics where grammar rules are looser.

In your case you want to say, "I want", which changes the form slightly. Then it becomes

> I want the things I love to be present more.

That is grammatically correct, though not necessarily the best way to express the idea. My first thought would be to say

> I want to be surrounded by the things I love.

Or

> I want the things I love all around me.

Answer (score 1):

*Present* in the way you are using it means something like "to give a presentation".

The word *presence* you may be trying to hit on - that's essentially a noun form of "being present" - but *presence* (or "being in the presence of X*) is more about being at a place with people or things rather than specifically being near things you love.

Try the idiom *within an arm's reach*:

> I want the things I love within an arm's reach.

Comment: Another useful idiom would be *surrounded by*: "I want to be surrounded by the things I love."